# Is there a way to get screenshot of the windows when it is locked using java?

Tags: java, awt, screenshot

I'm using below code to take a screenshot of the window, But it just returns blank image when the computer is locked (Alt + Ctrl + Del & lock)

Is there anyway we can take a screenshot on the locked computer using java.. Any help appreciated

```
 public void takeAScreenShot() throws AWTException, IOException 
 {      
        Dimension screenDimn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Rectangle screenBoundary = new Rectangle(0, 0, screenDimn.width, screenDimn.height);

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image =  robot.createScreenCapture(screenBoundary);

        File printScreenFile = new File("image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", printScreenFile);
    }
```

Comment: It isn't called "locking" without a reason. What would you want to do with the screenshot? If you want to know the running programs, for instance, you could send a remote `tasklist` command to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to capture that using Java (at least not that I know of). The reason being when computer is locked nothing is being rendered for the Robot to capture.

There might be some way using c / c++ to do the same but even that could be glitchy.

What i did was to use **[caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/)** to keep the screen from locking itself when executing long runs on remote machine.